# Copy data from one table to another sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

So I have a database containing the products I will be holding, within this database I have a basket table where users can add items they would like to buy. For some reason, **I am unable to take a selection** within the view window and copy that data into my basket table.

Here is the function I have created for moving the data.

```
def Move():
    if not tree.selection():
        error = tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Cannot move nothing to basket")
    else:
        result = tkMessageBox.askquestion('CCOS', 'Do you want to add this to the basket?', icon="warning")
        if result == 'yes':
            curItem = tree.selection()
            print(curItem)
            contents = (tree.item(curItem))
            selecteditem = contents['values']
            Database()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `basket` (product_name, product_qty, product_price) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", 
                            (str(PRODUCT_NAME.get()), int(PRODUCT_QTY.get()), int(PRODUCT_PRICE.get())))
            conn.commit()
            PRODUCT_ID.set("")
            PRODUCT_NAME.set("")
            PRODUCT_PRICE.set("")
            PRODUCT_QTY.set("")
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
```

> **Comment**:

I have a range of different functions in my code, `Database()` is its own function that creates the database and `cursor = conn.connect()`. I am not getting an error, but when i run the function, **no data is copied into the table**.

When I call `print(curItem)`, all that is outputted is : `('I002',)`

Here is the database function:

```
def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("main_storage.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (admin_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basket` (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, product_name TEXT, product_qty TEXT, product_price TEXT)")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = 'admin' AND `password` = 'admin'")
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `admin` (username, password) VALUES('admin', 'admin')")
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also is `Database()` supposed to be assigned to something? Where does `cursor` come from?

Comment: I have a range of different functions in my code, database is its own function that creates the database and cursor = conn.connect(). I am not getting an error, but when i run the function, no data is copied into the table

Comment: Well if this code is copy-pasted, everything after `execute(` is part of the sql string. You start with `"` but never close it

Comment: That was an error on my part, i have now re-run the code and I am still having the issue

Comment: When I call `print(curItem)`, all that is outputted is : `('I002',)`

Comment: *"no data is copied into the table"*: [Edit] your Question and show how `PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_QTY` etc., are related to the `Treeview`?