# Deleting selected items from tkinter returns sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: I002

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm Trying to delete an item in SQLite Database from a tree view in TKinter GUI. The tree view returns a value like I002. Tried to convert to string or in a variable also, nothing works. Here is the delete function code

```
def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pythontut.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `anno` (mem_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, daytype TEXT, time TEXT, audiofile TEXT)")
    
def Create():
    
    TIME = CHOUR.get() +":"+ CMIN.get() + ":"+ CSEC.get() + " "+CPERIOD.get()
    print(TIME)

    if  DAYTYPE.get() == "" or TIME == "":
        txt_result.config(text="Please complete the required field!", fg="red")
    else:
        Database()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `anno` (daytype, time, audiofile) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (str(DAYTYPE.get()), str(TIME), str(AUDIO_SELECTION.get())) )
        conn.commit()
        DAYTYPE.set("")
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        txt_result.config(text="Created a data!", fg="green")

def Read():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    Database()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `anno` ORDER BY `daytype` ASC")
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    for data in fetch:
        tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    txt_result.config(text="Successfully read the data from database", fg="black")

def Delete():
    
    selected_items = tree.selection()
    Database()  
    for selected_item in selected_items:          
        tree.delete(selected_item)
        print(str(selected_item))
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM anno WHERE mem_id = ?", (selected_items,))
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Returning this following error

```
cur.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: I002
```

I'm trying to Delete the selected items from the treeview in the TKinter as well as in the SQLite Database.

[image: GUI of ListView]

Comment: Don't use string concatenation for this, use parameter substitution as shown in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Tried even with the recommended method, still the same. Why does the selected value always contain values like I002? instead of 1 or 2 as it is in the table?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the table defintion (the create table statement) and the value of `selected_item` (note that in the code your are passing `selected_items`, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: What is in `selected_items` if you print it?

Comment: Judging by [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747066/copy-data-from-one-table-to-another-sqlite3), "I002" is a representation of `tree.selection`, so you are passing `tree.selection` to `cursor.execute` instead of the actual `id`.  Print your variables to check.

Comment: How do you populate the data to the treeview?

Comment: selected_items contains treeview selections on the GUI. (It returns a tuple I Guess). When multiple values selected it returns = ('I003', 'I004'). But in Table view the value of ID(as on image) is 3, 4 only. There is some additional letters I00 adds with it. That is the reason it is not taking in the SQL Query. May I know why it adds and how to take only the ID.

Comment: You need to provide details how you populate the data into the treeview so that we can know how the get the IDs you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching the below code that works. To get values from the selection, we need to use `tree.item(i, "values")[0]` the 0 represents the column. `i`  holds this strange value `I005` is from the tree view location (If the table has 5 items it shows 5th item as `I005`). Using the above command it takes out the value inside it & that can be stored in a variable (as shown below). That strange value they are calling it as `iid` (still no idea what it is). Below is the snippet attached that works in treeview as well as Database.

```
def DeleteRecord(id_num):
    con = sqlite3.connect("pythontut.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM anno WHERE mem_id = ?", (id_num,))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def DeleteData():
    try:
        messageDelete = tkMessageBox.askyesno("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this record?")
        if messageDelete > 0:
            select_items = tree.selection()
        for i in select_items:
            id_num = tree.item(i, "values")[0] #Returns data inside that treeview selection column 0 (iid)
            print(id_num)
            tree.delete(i)
            DeleteRecord(id_num)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```